# Redirect To New Page After Stripe Charge

Tags: javascript, c#, stripe-payments

Is it possible to redirect to a new webpage after the stripe charge completes? I am using .NET C#

Here is code below:

```
    <form action="/charge" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
    data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-name="Stripe.com"
    data-description="2 widgets"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

After, all I want to do is redirect to another page on my website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This client-side code will only turn the card information into a token -- it won't actually create a charge.

When you submit the form, the parameters (including the card token) will be sent to `/charge` (because that's what you set as the `action` attribute for the `<form>` tag). You then need to use these parameters to [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge). You can find out more in [this tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges).

Once the charge has been created, you can redirect the user to another page using whatever method is appropriate for your language and framework, e.g. in PHP you'd simply do:

```
header('Location: /success');
```

to redirect the user to `/success`.