# Redirecting Stripe to Confirmation Page After Charge

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am unable to redirect to a confirmation page after stripe checkout. Things break with the code below. Things work without error if I remove the header part.  The charge posts either way, but everything stays on the checkout page no matter what.  Am I doing something obviously wrong?

I found [a SO answer by one of their developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758565/redirect-to-new-page-after-stripe-charge), but it unfortunately doesn't work. The action strangely is not documented at all by Stripe for PHP, and support infuriatingly gave me the same exact answer of header redirect.

**PHP**

```
<?php
  require_once('./config.php');

// Variables passed by Ajax request. Shipping address, selection, and message attached via metadata to Stripe Tx.
  $token  = $_POST['token'];
  $price = $_POST['price'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $metadata = $_POST['metadata'];


// Post charge to Stripe with the variables.
try {
 $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email'    =>  $email,
      'source'   => $token

  ));

  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => $price,
      'currency' => 'usd',
      'metadata' => array("metadata" => $metadata)    
  ));

//Ajax hears and prints in console.log that Tx successful. Then page redirects.
echo  'success';

header('Location: /success.php');

} catch(Stripe\CardError $e) {
  // When the card declines.
    echo $token;

}


?>
```

**JS**

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_00000000',
    image: '/logo.png',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token, args) {
        // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
        // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
        console.log(token)
        $.ajax({
            url: '/charge.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { token: token.id, email: token.email, price: price, metadata: metadata },

            success: function(data) {
                if (data == 'success') {
                    console.log("Things went well for once, success!");
                    console.log(metadata);
                } else {
                    console.log("Charge Error");
                    console.log(metadata);

                }

            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log("Ajax Error");
                console.log(data);
            }
        }); // end ajax call
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change location with **[`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)** after outputting content to the DOM:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

Removing `echo 'success'` will fix the problem.

Comment: How do I pass back a successful message to Ajax then?  I get an error now since it can't see the success.

I suppose it can be triggered from PHP of the success page, but that's getting out of my depth. I was just hoping to only have this page for the PHP.  :/ I will update this when I find the answer.

Comment: I see the additional problem, and you have two options. You don't need to check that the `data` is success; you just need to check for `data`. A simple `if (data) {}` will cover that. Also, you don't **need** to redirect from `charge.php` if you are only posting to it via AJAX. Remove the `header()` call entirely, and redirect on the JavaScript side via `window.location.href = '/success.php'`.

Comment: Thank you! After thinking about it for some time, the PHP redirect is unnecessary, but I still wasn't sure if this is the best way. I have passed along this question to Stripe in hopes they will update their documentation to be a bit more clear. The abstraction of having a token posted server side is necessary, but I am only at a level of PHP where I can make basic templates. All of this JS>JQuery>Ajax>PHP and back to PHP is not at all trivial without code to reference, and I just ran out of luck on this problem because there were no easy answers.